# Compact set whose closure isn't compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I've been killing myself trying to think of a compact set (in the Borel-Lebesgue sense) whose closure isn't compact. Obviously not considering a Hausdorff space, but any topological space in the most general possible way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{N}$ generated by $$\{\{1, i\}: i\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ Then:

- Is $\tau$ compact?
- What is the closure of $\{1\}$?
- Is $\{1\}$ compact? (HINT: it's finite . . .)

Comment: $\tau$ is not compact since the generator that you described is an open cover of $\mathbb{N}$. The closure of ${1}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ since closed sets are $\mathbb{N}$ and those that don't contain $1$. $\{1\}$ is compact as are all singletons. So great thx !

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and fix $p\in X$. Let $\tau=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U\subseteq X:p\in U\}$; then $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, $\{p\}$ is compact, $\operatorname{cl}\{p\}=X$, and

$$\big\{\{p,x\}:x\in X\big\}$$

is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: Better written than mine, +1.

Comment: @Noah: On the other hand, yours is a reasonable hint. (Also +1.)